# Удаление комментариев без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такая задачка, надо организвать удаление комментариев с помощью AJAX(без перезагрузки страницы). Может кто знает как написать скрипт? Сам я совсем слаб в JS.
Буду очень благодарен всем ответившим.

Answer (score 4):

Например на сервере генерируем html вида:

```
<?foreach($comments as $comment):?>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="author">   <?=$comment['author']?>  </div>
        <div class="content">  <?=$comment['content']?> </div>

        <!-- если пользователь имеете право удалить этот комментарий -->
        <?if($_SESSION['username'] === $comment['author']):?>
            <!-- показываем кнопку удаления -->
            <button class="remove" id="remove_<?=$comment['id']?>">
        <?endif?>
    </div>
<?endforeach?>
```

Соответственно теперь выбрав все кнопки по css классу мы мы можем получить id каждого из них для передачи на сервер, ну а теперь что касается клиентского кода.

```
$(".comment .remove").on('click', function(){
     var $button = $(this);
     var commentId = this.id.slice(7); // обрежем id чтобы получить число

     // делаем POST запрос на сервер
     $.post("/comments_remove.php", {id : commentId}, function( serverResponse ){
         if( serverResponse === 'ok' ) { // если сервер ответил ok - все хорошо
              $button.parent().remove(); // удаляем HTML комментария
              // тут можем еще что-либо сделать
         }
         else {
              // в противном случае комментарий не был удален
              // тут можем как-то сообщить об ошибке
         }
     })
})
```

Ну а на сервере, comment_remove.php, как-то так:

```
// mysql connection here....
if($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] === 'POST') {
     if( is_numeric($_POST['id']) ) {
         $commentId = (int)$_POST['id'];
         $commentDbData = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=' . $commentId);
         $comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($commentDbData);
         if(!empty($comment)) { // если такой комментарий действительно существует
              // перепроверим - имеет ли право пользователь удалить этот комментарий
              if($comment[ 'author' ] === $_SESSION[ 'username' ]) {
                   if( mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=" . $commentId) ) {
                        echo 'ok'; // все в порядке, оповещаем клиента
                   }
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Ну вот как-то вот так, если не планируется логика обработки ошибок удаления, тогда на сервере можно сделать много проще, что-то типа:

```
  mysql_query('DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=' . (int)$_POST['id'] .
                   ' AND author="' . $_SESSION[ 'author' ] . '"');
  echo 'ok';
```

В любом случае вам необходимо иметь возможность получить идентификатор конкретного комментария и не забывать перепроверять все что нам "сказал" клиент на сервере.

Удачи в реализации.

Comment: Ух ты, как сложно то все. Но спасибо за подробное объяснение, попытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, на самом деле все очень просто, сложным только кажется.

Answer (score -1):

Используй jQuery, в разы легче, если понимаешь в программировании сможешь легко разобраться за несколько часов (куча документации на русском). Общий алгоритм примерно таков:
Находишь HTML-элемент содержащий коментарий (который в последующем нужно будет удалить), удаляешь, посылаешь запрос AJAX'ом на сервер который будет содержать ID коментария, сервер принимает, удалят с базы, возвращает клиенту ответ что всё "ок". Всё.

Comment: Да, я знаю алгоритм, проблема в том, что комментариев на странице много, и как каждому комментарию прописать уникальный id, чтобы скрипт понял какой именно комментарий надо скрыть со страницы?

Comment: Идентифицируйте каждый коментарий в базе при вставке, и вставляйте идентификатор в ID (html) при вытаскивании.